# Is NIST testing all the round 2 submissions to quantum-resistant crypto?

Tags: nist, post-quantum-cryptography

Is NIST confirming the self-published quantum-resistant crypto round 2 data and do they make that available to the public when they do?

Comment: Well, I suppose that's a nice thing about a competition: It's in the interest of the competitors to unveil flaws in each other's submissions, so the organizer only has to do some basic checks...

Comment: And so the only way to narrow down a good candidate to study until NIST announces winners is by reading everyone else's comments and running simulations on every submission?

Comment: NIST isn't always that transparent about their internal evaluation processes. Presumably they're validating and analyzing everything they can, the best they can, but many of the submitters have said they get very little feedback. But usually their choices are mostly consistent with the general consensus.